# Псевдоелементы не видно при печати

Tags: html, css, print

Есть псевдоелементы :before
имеет следующий код:

```
.sqrt:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
```

Собственно это линия сверху блока. Так видно, но когда вывожу на печать, псевдоелемент пропадает. Может, кто подскажет, как вывести его на печать?

Comment: Включить печать фона в настройках браузера?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/